# idempotents of a character

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $\Delta = Gal (K/\mathbb{Q})$ and $\chi: \Delta \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ be a non-trivial Dirichlet character, $e_{\chi} = (1/\mid \Delta \mid) \sum_{\sigma \in \Delta} \chi (\sigma) \sigma$ be the corresponding idempotent.

I am trying to understand why the following statement is true:

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p \not \mid [K:\mathbb{Q}]$. Since $K \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) \cap \mathbb{R}$, we have that $\sum_{\chi} e_{\chi} = 1$, where $\chi$ runs over all $p$-adic Dirichlet characters of $\Delta$.

PS it's on page 15 of the paper of Thaine on Ideal Class Groups of real abelian number fields in Annals of Math, 128.

Comment: This is just a statement about the representation theory of compact groups (specifically, the decomposition of the regular representation); it has nothing to do with Galois theory.  (Also I think that the right-hand side of the equality should be $1$ at the identity and $0$ elsewhere, not identically $1$.)

Comment: Ah, I see that these aren't just complex representations, so I guess that there's some more to it.  I don't think I understand the assumptions.  You say that $K$ is a number field, and then speak of $[K : \mathbb Q_p]$; do you mean $[K : \mathbb Q]$?  Then you also say $K \subseteq \mathbb Q_p$; is that really what you mean?

Comment: The assumptions are: $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is not divisible by $p$ and $K\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)\cap \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Anent the recent edit, I assume that it should be (as @AnweshRay says) $K \subseteq \mathbb Q(\mu_p) \cap \mathbb R$, with a lowercase $p$, not $K \subseteq \mathbb Q(\zeta_P)$, with a capital $P$?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption $p\nmid [K:\mathbb{Q}]$ means that $p$ does not divide the order of $\Delta$, in particular, the assumption in the paper is that $K\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$. By the decomposition $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}=\mu_{p-1}\times (1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ all $p$-adic characters $\chi$ have target in $\mu_{p-1}$. Expanding $\sum_{\chi} e_{\chi}$ you get $\sum_{\sigma\in \Delta} \{\frac{1}{\lvert\Delta\rvert}\sum_{\chi} \chi(\sigma)\}\sigma$. Since $K\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$, the number of characters $\chi$ is equal to the order of $\Delta$. Observe that $\frac{1}{\lvert\Delta\rvert}\sum_{\chi} \chi(\sigma)=0$ if $\sigma\neq 1$ (once again use the assumption here, if $\sigma\neq 1$, there is character $\psi$ such that $\psi(\sigma)\neq 1$, multiply the expression by $\psi(\sigma)$ to see that it does not change) and is $1$ otherwise by the observation we just made. Therefore, $\sum_{\chi} e_{\chi}=1$.

Comment: A TeX note:  `$p \not| [K : \mathbb Q]$` ($p \not| [K : \mathbb Q]$) should be `$p \nmid [K : \mathbb Q]$` ($p \nmid [K : \mathbb Q]$), and `$\mid\Delta\mid$` (as in $a \mid\Delta\mid b$) should be `$\lvert\Delta\rvert$` (as in $a \lvert\Delta\rvert b$), or at worst `$|\Delta|$` (as in $a |\Delta| b$).  I have edited accordingly.